# Calculate a probability someone will do the same N tasks from X tasks as you

Tags: probability

I got a rather fun and interesting task from my professor.

The task is as follows: **From 30 (x) tasks choose 8 (n) tasks you want to solve. Then as an additional task calculate the probability of someone from 24 (y) people choose the same N tasks as you did.**

I tried: $${\frac YX * \frac NY}$$

**CORRECT SOLUTION**: $${1-(1 - {\frac 1{\binom{x}{n}}})^{y}}$$

**EXPLANATION:**

1. **First we have to get all possible combinations.** We do this by doing: $$combinations = \binom{x}{n}$$ or in this problems case: $$combinations = \binom{30}{8}$$
2. **Secondly, we need to get the probability of someone picking same tasks as me**. We get it by this formula: $$p = \frac 1{combinations}$$
3. **Thirdly, we need to find probability that an individual student doesn't choose the same 8 tasks as us.** $$q = 1 - p$$
4. **Now we calculate the probability none of those Y students don't choose the same 8 tasks as me:** $$Q = q^{y}$$
5. **Finally, we subtract by 1 to get probability someone will choose the same N tasks from X tasks like us.** $$FINAL = 1 - Q$$

Comment: Assuming people choose the tasks uniformly at random and independently of everyone else then;  how many ways are there to choose $8$ from $30$?  What's the probability that a single individual will choose the same $8$ as you did?  What's the probability that each of $24$ people will choose a different $8$ then you did?

Comment: For first question it should be 30! / 8! if I am not mistaken. The second question is the one I need help with. And for third again, 24! / 8!. Should be correct?

Comment: You are mistaken for the first question.  Your answer for the third does not make sense since it is greater than $1$, hence can not be a probability.

Comment: Then I am going to say it should be 8! / 30! and 8! / 24!. If it is not that then I have no idea :/

Comment: I think you are just guessing.  Try the same problem with smaller numbers to get a sense of how it works.  Start small, with $3$ tasks and $1$ choice.  Move up to slightly bigger numbers like $5$ tasks with $2$ choices.

Comment: I think I figured out my issue. It should be 30C8 since that gets all of the possible combinations. And to get a probability it should be 1 / 30C8. Hopefully that is correct

Comment: Good!  Yes, that is correct for the first part.  And you also have the right probability $p$,  for the second part.  That tells us that $q=1-p$ is the probability that a given individual does not choose the same $8$ tasks that you did.  It follows that $q^{24}$ is the probability that none of the $24$ people choose the same $8$ that you did (trusting that you are not one of the $24$).  Can you finish from here?

Comment: Note:  if you add those computations to your post, people will retract their close votes (or, at least, no new close votes should be cast). That way the question will stay open.

Comment: I should add:  as you will have notices, $\binom {30}8=5852925$ is pretty big, so the probability that anyone out of the $24$ matches some given list is vanishingly small.

Comment: So you are saying I should now just do (1 - p)^24 (I will solve parentheses first)to get a probability that none of those people choose the same 8 tasks as me?

Comment: Yes.  And so the final answer, the probability that at least one of the $24$ people match you is just $1-(1-p)^{24}$.  As I say, the answer should be effectively $0$.  Of course, in real life the choices are not independent...I;'m sure some tasks are more appealing than others.

Comment: Thank you for your help!! My final answer turns out to be 0.0000041

Comment: Yes, I get the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $\binom{30}{8} = 5\,852\,925$ ways to pick 8 tasks out of 30. The probability of you picking a particular set (assuming you choose uniformly independently at random, i.e., no "pick easiest tasks") is one in this.

If everybody selects in the same way, call $p$ the probability somebody picks the same as you, the probability she doesn't is $1 - p$. The probability that $n$ people all choose different than you is $(1 - p)^n$, so that at least one chooses the same is $1 - (1 - p)^n$. In your particular case, $p$ is very small and $n$ isn't too large, so we can approximate:

$\begin{align*}
   1 - (1 - p)^n
     &=       1 - \sum_{0 \le k \le n} (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} p^k \\
     &=       \sum_{1 \le k \le n} (-1)^{k + 1} \binom{n}{k} p^k \\
     &\approx n p 
\end{align*}$

the last because $\binom{n}{1} = n$, the other terms are negligible. Thus in your case around 24 in $5\,852\,925$, around one in 250 thousand.

Comment: You and @lulu helped me a lot with your explanations!! Thank you a lot!!